# Emails sent from Server1 reaches the destination from Server 2

Tags: exchange-server, high-availability, exchange-server-2010

**Question**

Outbound emails sent through EXCH-S01 or EXCH-S02 are always routed to EXCH-S02 before leaving the organization network in Exchange 2010 DAG. Why?

**Configuration**

[image: DAG Configuration]

This is a simple DAG with two exchange servers and a fileshare witness (not included in the figure). S1 and S2 are the exchange servers hosting OWA1 and OWA2 respectively.

**System Information**

*Send Connector: Internet*

```
AddressSpaces                : {SMTP:*;1}
AuthenticationCredential     : 
Comment                      : 
ConnectedDomains             : {}
ConnectionInactivityTimeOut  : 00:10:00
DNSRoutingEnabled            : True
DomainSecureEnabled          : False
Enabled                      : True
ErrorPolicies                : Default
ForceHELO                    : False
Fqdn                         : email.fabrikam.ca
HomeMTA                      : Microsoft MTA
HomeMtaServerId              : EXCH-S02
Identity                     : Internet
IgnoreSTARTTLS               : False
IsScopedConnector            : False
IsSmtpConnector              : True
LinkedReceiveConnector       : 
MaxMessageSize               : unlimited
Name                         : Internet
Port                         : 25
ProtocolLoggingLevel         : None
RequireOorg                  : False
RequireTLS                   : False
SmartHostAuthMechanism       : None
SmartHosts                   : {}
SmartHostsString             : 
SmtpMaxMessagesPerConnection : 20
SourceIPAddress              : 0.0.0.0
SourceRoutingGroup           : Exchange Routing Group (DWBGZMFD01QNBJR)
SourceTransportServers       : {EXCH-S02, EXCH-S01}
TlsAuthLevel                 : 
TlsDomain                    : 
UseExternalDNSServersEnabled : True
```

*Receive Connector "EXCH-S02\From EXCH-S01"*

```
RunspaceId                              : c5d80334-209b-4974-b6ef-105e3db469b4
AuthMechanism                           : Tls, Integrated, BasicAuth, BasicAuthRequireTLS, ExchangeServer
Banner                                  : 
BinaryMimeEnabled                       : True
Bindings                                : {0.0.0.0:25}
ChunkingEnabled                         : True
DefaultDomain                           : 
DeliveryStatusNotificationEnabled       : True
EightBitMimeEnabled                     : True
BareLinefeedRejectionEnabled            : False
DomainSecureEnabled                     : False
EnhancedStatusCodesEnabled              : True
LongAddressesEnabled                    : False
OrarEnabled                             : False
SuppressXAnonymousTls                   : False
AdvertiseClientSettings                 : False
Fqdn                                    : EXCH-S02.fabrikam.ca
Comment                                 : 
Enabled                                 : True
ConnectionTimeout                       : 00:10:00
ConnectionInactivityTimeout             : 00:05:00
MessageRateLimit                        : unlimited
MessageRateSource                       : IPAddress
MaxInboundConnection                    : 5000
MaxInboundConnectionPerSource           : 20
MaxInboundConnectionPercentagePerSource : 100
MaxHeaderSize                           : 64 KB (65,536 bytes)
MaxHopCount                             : 60
MaxLocalHopCount                        : 8
MaxLogonFailures                        : 3
MaxMessageSize                          : 10 MB (10,485,760 bytes)
MaxProtocolErrors                       : 5
MaxRecipientsPerMessage                 : 200
PermissionGroups                        : ExchangeUsers, ExchangeServers, ExchangeLegacyServers
PipeliningEnabled                       : True
ProtocolLoggingLevel                    : None
RemoteIPRanges                          : {10.1.0.3, 10.1.0.1}
RequireEHLODomain                       : False
RequireTLS                              : False
EnableAuthGSSAPI                        : False
ExtendedProtectionPolicy                : None
LiveCredentialEnabled                   : False
TlsDomainCapabilities                   : {}
Server                                  : EXCH-S02
SizeEnabled                             : EnabledWithoutValue
TarpitInterval                          : 00:00:05
MaxAcknowledgementDelay                 : 00:00:30
AdminDisplayName                        : 
ExchangeVersion                         : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
Name                                    : From EXCH-S01
DistinguishedName                       : CN=From EXCH-S01,CN=SMTP Receive Connectors,CN=Protocols,CN=EXCH-S02,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=fabrikam,CN=
                                          Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=fabrikam,DC=ca
Identity                                : EXCH-S02\From EXCH-S01
Guid                                    : a040ff87-900f-4a21-ad68-c9c095940686
ObjectCategory                          : fabrikam.ca/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Smtp-Receive-Connector
ObjectClass                             : {top, msExchSmtpReceiveConnector}
WhenChanged                             : 4/8/2017 9:10:54 AM
WhenCreated                             : 1/21/2012 10:15:06 PM
WhenChangedUTC                          : 4/8/2017 1:10:54 PM
WhenCreatedUTC                          : 1/22/2012 3:15:06 AM
OrganizationId                          : 
OriginatingServer                       : DC01.fabrikam.ca
IsValid                                 : True
```

*Exchange Server EXCH-S01*

```
RunspaceId                        : c5d80334-209b-4974-b6ef-105e3db469b4
Name                              : EXCH-S01
DataPath                          : D:\Exchange Server\V14\Mailbox
Domain                            : fabrikam.ca
Edition                           : Enterprise
ExchangeLegacyDN                  : /o=fabrikam/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=EXCH-S01
ExchangeLegacyServerRole          : 0
Fqdn                              : EXCH-S01.fabrikam.ca
CustomerFeedbackEnabled           : 
InternetWebProxy                  : 
IsHubTransportServer              : True
IsClientAccessServer              : True
IsExchange2007OrLater             : True
IsEdgeServer                      : False
IsMailboxServer                   : True
IsE14OrLater                      : True
IsProvisionedServer               : False
IsUnifiedMessagingServer          : False
NetworkAddress                    : {ncacn_vns_spp:EXCH-S01, netbios:EXCH-S01, ncacn_np:EXCH-S01, ncacn_spx:EXCH-S01, ncacn_ip_tcp:EXCH-S01.fabrikam.ca, ncalrpc:EXCH-S01}
OrganizationalUnit                : fabrikam.ca/EXCH-S01
AdminDisplayVersion               : Version 14.3 (Build 123.4)
Site                              : fabrikam.ca/Configuration/Sites/fabrikam
ServerRole                        : Mailbox, ClientAccess, HubTransport
ErrorReportingEnabled             : 
StaticDomainControllers           : {}
StaticGlobalCatalogs              : {}
StaticConfigDomainController      : 
StaticExcludedDomainControllers   : {}
CurrentDomainControllers          : {}
CurrentGlobalCatalogs             : {}
CurrentConfigDomainController     : 
ProductID                         : 02064-110-8022196-75615
IsExchange2007TrialEdition        : False
IsExpiredExchange2007TrialEdition : False
RemainingTrialPeriod              : 00:00:00
IsValid                           : True
ExchangeVersion                   : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
DistinguishedName                 : CN=EXCH-S01,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=fabrikam,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=fabrikam,DC=
                                    ca
Identity                          : EXCH-S01
Guid                              : 72736c62-2931-4128-bca5-73b233142f3b
ObjectCategory                    : fabrikam.ca/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Exchange-Server
ObjectClass                       : {top, server, msExchExchangeServer}
WhenChanged                       : 4/8/2017 5:23:00 PM
WhenCreated                       : 5/21/2011 8:29:21 PM
WhenChangedUTC                    : 4/8/2017 9:23:00 PM
WhenCreatedUTC                    : 5/22/2011 12:29:21 AM
OrganizationId                    : 
OriginatingServer                 : DC01.fabrikam.ca
```

*Exchange Server EXCH-S02*

```
RunspaceId                        : c5d80334-209b-4974-b6ef-105e3db469b4
Name                              : EXCH-S02
DataPath                          : D:\Exchange Server\V14\Mailbox
Domain                            : fabrikam.ca
Edition                           : Enterprise
ExchangeLegacyDN                  : /o=fabrikam/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=EXCH-S02
ExchangeLegacyServerRole          : 0
Fqdn                              : EXCH-S02.fabrikam.ca
CustomerFeedbackEnabled           : 
InternetWebProxy                  : 
IsHubTransportServer              : True
IsClientAccessServer              : True
IsExchange2007OrLater             : True
IsEdgeServer                      : False
IsMailboxServer                   : True
IsE14OrLater                      : True
IsProvisionedServer               : False
IsUnifiedMessagingServer          : False
NetworkAddress                    : {ncacn_vns_spp:EXCH-S02, netbios:EXCH-S02, ncacn_np:EXCH-S02, ncacn_spx:EXCH-S02, ncacn_ip_tcp:EXCH-S02.fabrikam.ca, ncalrpc:EXCH-S02}
OrganizationalUnit                : fabrikam.ca/EXCH-S02
AdminDisplayVersion               : Version 14.3 (Build 123.4)
Site                              : fabrikam.ca/Configuration/Sites/fabrikam
ServerRole                        : Mailbox, ClientAccess, HubTransport
ErrorReportingEnabled             : 
StaticDomainControllers           : {}
StaticGlobalCatalogs              : {}
StaticConfigDomainController      : 
StaticExcludedDomainControllers   : {}
CurrentDomainControllers          : {}
CurrentGlobalCatalogs             : {}
CurrentConfigDomainController     : 
ProductID                         : 02064-110-8022196-75900
IsExchange2007TrialEdition        : False
IsExpiredExchange2007TrialEdition : False
RemainingTrialPeriod              : 00:00:00
IsValid                           : True
ExchangeVersion                   : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
DistinguishedName                 : CN=EXCH-S02,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=fabrikam,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=fabrikam,DC=
                                    ca
Identity                          : EXCH-S02
Guid                              : 0f25a4ee-2e54-4c9c-840d-a1ab5f107cfa
ObjectCategory                    : fabrikam.ca/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Exchange-Server
ObjectClass                       : {top, server, msExchExchangeServer}
WhenChanged                       : 9/20/2014 10:20:32 AM
WhenCreated                       : 1/21/2012 5:58:57 PM
WhenChangedUTC                    : 9/20/2014 2:20:32 PM
WhenCreatedUTC                    : 1/21/2012 10:58:57 PM
OrganizationId                    : 
OriginatingServer                 : DC01.fabrikam.ca
```

I will be happy to provide more information if required.

**What I've done so far**

1. Reset the activation preference.
2. Noticed HomeMtaServerId set to `EXCH-S02` in the send connector. But realized Exchnage Server 2010 does not use that parameter anymore.

I am very eager to find out what is causing this.